# Cannot resolve symbol setLatestEventInfo

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am implementing one PendingIntent example in Android Studio.. but The NoticationClass seems to be a bit problem ..

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                NotificationManager notif=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notify=new Notification(R.drawable.noti,tittle,System.currentTimeMillis());

                notify.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),subject,body,pending);

            }
```

---

this is my Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "testproject.example.com.testproject"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

}
```

I have got one suggestion to use NotificationBuilder but that was replacement of NotificationCompat class , which is not present in my code .

I have seen multiple Solution of this system but not able to implement any of it

.

what are the other alternatives of setLatestEventInfo.

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: what is your `CompileSdkVersion` ??

Comment: I Updated My Gradle , CompileSdkVersion  is 23

Comment: wait i posted Answer.

Comment: I posted answer see below.

Answer (score 1):

`setLatestEventInfo` is removed in `Api 23`.

for more detail visit this : https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.html.

To Make support `Api 23 and upper` you have to Implement like below way.

declare this global

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

and then check like this

```
if (currentapiVersion > LOLLIPOP_MR1) {

            notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent); // This method is removed from the Android 6.0
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    this);
            notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(text).setWhen(time)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text).build();

            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        }
```

In else part you have to implement `NotificationCompat.Builder` that is only way.

## UpDate :

Working Example this way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, HomeActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);

    b.setAutoCancel(true)
     .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
     .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())         
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
     .setTicker("Hearty365")            
     .setContentTitle("Default notification")
     .setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
     .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
     .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
     .setContentInfo("Info");


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());
```

Comment: I am finding this a bit incomplete , Can you please post complete Pending Intent Example ?

Comment: Why declare a variable for `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`? It  is already a global variable... So, all you did there was make an alias

Comment: @cricket_007 for OP can understand it that's why.

Comment: @NeerajVerma if my answer is helpful to you then you can mark as accepted so it help other.

Comment: Give me some time to test your code , I will sure update that , thanx for help ;)

Comment: @NeerajVerma take your time.